# Proove that Unions and intersections of recursively enumerable sets are also recursively enumerable

Tags: computability

How do I prove that Unions and intersections of recursively enumerable sets
are also recursively enumerable?

Comment: Finite unions and intersections? Just $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$, that is? (Effectively given countable unions are also possible).

Comment: Yes Finite unions and intersections.

Comment: What's your working definition of r.e.? A set $X$ is r.e. iff there's some Turing machine $M$ such that $X = \{x\in\Bbb N\mid M\downarrow x\}$ ? (where $M\downarrow x$ means "$M$ halts on input $x$") Or something different?

Comment: That is correct. A set is recursively enumerable if and only if it can be accepted by a Turing machine.

Comment: Just to be a stickler, what does "accept" mean? Halt in an "accepting state"? or just, not run forever?

Comment: Accept means it will halt

Comment: Ah, then I'm ok with my answer :) Sometimes the exact definition varies in a detail or two which would affect the descriptions of the TMs for $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $A, B$ are accepted by Turing machines $M_A, M_B$ respectively.

[$A\cap B$] A TM that implements the following algorithm will accept $A\cap B$:

On input $x$,

1. run $M_A$ on $x$;
2. run $M_B$ on $x$;
3. accept $x$ (halt).

If $M_A$ or $M_B$ doesn't halt on $x$, so be it: in either case, this machine won't halt either, as it will never reach the next step, so it won't accept $x$.

[$A\cup B$] A TM that implements the following algorithm will accept $A\cup B$:

On input $x$,

```
loop
    run $M_A$ for one more step on input $x$;
    if $M_A$ has accepted $x$, then accept $x$ (halt, return)

    run $M_B$ for one more step on input $x$;
    if $M_B$ has accepted $x$, then accept $x$ (halt, return)
end loop
```

The TM runs the two TMs $M_A$ and $M_B$ on $x$ "in parallel", one step at a time. If either accepts $x$, then it accepts $x$; if neither does, it will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more intuitive to think of a r.e. set as the ordered list of values output by a machine, rather than simply running it on a given input and asking whether it halts or not. The notions are equivalent.

Countable unions: you can construct a "volcano". Perform machine 1 for one step, then machine 2 for one step and machine 1 for one step, then machines 3,2,1 for one step, then machines 4,3,2,1 in one step, … At any point, if one of the internal machines outputs a number, get the volcano to output that number.

In this way, each internal machine gets to run for countably infinitely many time steps, so each internal machine will output anything it was ever going to output.

So the volcano outputs every number which any internal machine outputs.

Comment: Countable intersections of r.e. languages are _not_ necessarily r.e. For example the set of "all Turing machines that never halt (on the empty tape)" is the intersection of "all machines that run for at least $n$ steps" (which is even computable). But the non-halting machines cannot be r.e. because that would make the halting problem decidable.

Comment: Hah. That's embarrassing. I'll remember not to answer questions early in the morning in future. Thanks.