# Two recursively enumerable sets $A$ and $B$ such that none of union, intersection, one subtracting the other is recursive?

Tags: computer-science, computability

I was reading the two questions posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794868/union-intersection-set-theoretic-difference-of-recursively-enumerable-sets) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651728/proove-that-unions-and-intersections-of-recursively-enumerable-sets-are-also-rec) and their answers, and my question here is motivated by them.

Do there exist $2$ recursively enumerable sets $A$ and $B$ where none of the $4$ sets$$A \cap B, \quad A \cup B, \quad A - B, \quad B - A$$is recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be your favorite r.e. but not recursive set, and consider
$$ A = \{4n+1\mid n\in S\} \cup \{4n+2\mid n\in S\} \\
B = \{4n+2\mid n\in S\} \cup \{4n+3\mid n\in S\} $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible you could include some more detail? No worries if not.

Comment: @user389821: Which kind of extra detail are you envisaging?

Comment: Actually never mind, I should probably try to grapple with this a bit longer myself before asking for more help.